# Composer VCS repo reading every version. Very slow

Tags: version-control, composer-php

I have a VCS override as such:

```
"repositories": [{
     "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/mygithub/myrepo.git",
      "no-api": true
}],
```

and require as:

```
"repo/repo": "dev-mybranch",
```

It works fine, however the time it takes to composer install is unacceptable. This is because it is reading every version of the source repository first. Like this:

```
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.101)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.102)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.103)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.104)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.105)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.106)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.107)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.108)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.109)
Reading composer.json of repo/repo (1.11.110)
```

There are well over a thousand version.

**Can this be stopped?** Why can't it just read the one version that I need?

Comment: I can tell you how to make it even slower - remove the "no-api": true setting :). Truth be told for me it is actually ok with "no-api": true, now other operations in the process take more time.

Comment: I think the reason it has to check all the versions is that the repositories are defined independently of the packages. So in theory, this repo could contain code for _any_ of your packages.

Comment: A solution could be a fork repo where you only keep a single branch.